# SQL INSERT INTO Error

Tags: c#, ms-access

I'm inserting a record with this SQL command

> INSERT INTO Deployment (DateTime, Type, Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment)
>   VALUES ('May 20, 2013','LAPTOP','ASUS','K55V','ABCD1234','10F HRD');

But an error popped up saying

> Syntax Error in INSERT INTO statement

DateTime is a text type. What should I do?

Comment: Your syntax looks OK, so check that you've got all your types correct. Are any of those strings too long for their columns?

Comment: All of the columns are string and are limited up to 50 characters. Although, I would like to change the DateTime into actual DateTime type. I'm trying to insert this code on C#, but this error always shows up. I was thinking the DateTime type might be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

I think this error might occur if you try to use reserved words in the query (as stated [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/892608)).  Try wrapping the `DateTime` column in brackets:

```
INSERT INTO Deployment ([DateTime], Type, Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment) VALUES ('May 20, 2013','LAPTOP','ASUS','K55V','ABCD1234','10F HRD');
```

Probably a better solution is to change that column name.

Comment: Thanks, Ben Reich. The code works on MS Access but not on C#. Do you have any more ideas to insert a record with a date?

Comment: Do you have the ability to rename the column?  If so, I would recommend trying that.

Comment: I've renamed the column. The error still shows up. Thanks for the help, Ben Reich.

Comment: Does the table have any constraints (primary, unique, foreign key) that the insertion might violate?

Comment: I have an AutoNumber-type column with a primary key. That's all there is.

Comment: If you're doing this from C#, try using SQL parameters (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).  This might give you a better error message, and has the added benefit of protecting you from SQL Injection (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Ben Reich, I have a question. Would the OleDb Parameters help if I use them in C# in accordance to this SQL command?

Comment: I'm not sure, but the `OleDbParameter` might help for the same reason I said `SqlParameter` would.  In fact, they are both implementations of the `DbParameter` abstract class.

Answer (score 1):

Both `DateTime` and `Type` are [problem names](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html).  Enclose both in square brackets in your `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO Deployment ([DateTime], [Type], Brand, Model, SerialNo, Assignment)
VALUES ('May 20, 2013','LAPTOP','ASUS','K55V','ABCD1234','10F HRD');
```

Download Allen Browne's free [Database Issue Checker Utility](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueChecker.html) and use it to examine your Access db files.  In addition to problem object names, it can alert you to other troublesome issues with your databases.

Comment: Can I ask you, HansUp? Am I going to use the sharp(#) for the date?

Comment: No, you said [DateTime] is text data type, so enclose the date value in quotes same as the values you supply for all the other text fields.